# Update parent entry `dateUpdated` on child entry save

Tags: entry

I got a bit of help with this from Discord. Here is what I have:

```
Event::on(Entry::class, Element::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE, function (ModelEvent $e) {
  $entry = $e->sender;

  if ($entry->sectionId !== 7) {
    return;
  }

  if ($entry->typeId !== 9) {
    return;
  }

  $parent = $entry->getParent();

  if (!$parent) {
    return;
  }

  $parent->dateUpdated = $entry->dateUpdated;
  Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($parent);
});
```

The trouble is that the `if` conditions aren't working; with the above code, the parent entry is not updated. As soon as I remove those two if statements, the code works and the parent is updated. However, I don't want to run this on all sections/structures.

Does anyone know what might be going wrong? I've checked the section/type IDs many times :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using `!==` to compare your `sectionId` and `typeId`.

In PHP using this will [compare the value as well as the type](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Here, since you are comparing an `int` with a `string`, although the value is a match, the type isn't, your first conditional is failing and nothing happens.

Try using `!=` instead:

```php
Event::on(Entry::class, Element::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE, function (ModelEvent $e) {
  $entry = $e->sender;

  if ($entry->sectionId != 7) {
    return;
  }

  if ($entry->typeId != 9) {
    return;
  }

  $parent = $entry->getParent();

  if (!$parent) {
    return;
  }

  $parent->dateUpdated = $entry->dateUpdated;
  Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($parent);
});
```

Comment: Oh boy...that was easy. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by var_dumping or logging the value of sectionId and TypeId, since its not saving parent, it hits one of the if statements and returns before doing anything.